# Why is my include tag deleting everything after it?

Tags: php

I have a PHP file included but everything after the `<?php include 'RandomFile.php' ?>` gets thrown away, I have no clue why! I need help with this.

RandomFile.php has the contents of:

```
require 'cons.php';
mysql_connect($URL, $USER, $PASS, $DBN);
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM song";

// Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

// Loop the recordset $rs
// Each row will be made into an array ($row) using mysql_fetch_array
if($rs === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {


    // Write the value of the column FirstName (which is now in the array $row)
    echo $row['url'] . "<br />";

}
// Close the database connection
mysql_close();
```

So Basically after the `<?php include 'randomfile.php' ?>` is included all my html after that isn't showing up visually in my browser but if I go back and edit the file it is there???

Comment: Why are people voting down on this I thought this was a site for help not beating people up when they come for help???????

Comment: If there is an fatal error in your included file, it will halt the script. Are you getting errors in your server's error log?

Comment: Yes it says no database selected and all the html after that in the developer tools on chrome show that all my code after that was dropped

Comment: ...maybe you should select a database then.

Comment: There you go. I'm guessing that throws an error and your script halts. So it never executes the rest of your code.

Comment: Have you forgot to add <?php to the beginning of RandomFile.php (and perhaps cons.php)? You don't select db so you should get "No database selected" and it should die.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is this line:

```
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
```

If there is an error connecting to the database (as you described in your comment: "no database selected"), the execution will "die" and no more of the page will be sent to the browser.

As the code comment says, you need better error handling, but you might conceivably *temporarily* change the `die` to an `echo` and then the execution will continue.

Comment: Thank you it was because it was a "die" rather than a "echo"

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that `cons.php` is the connection file for your database. You need to specify the full path to `cons.php`. From the [PHP Manual for require](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php):

> **require** is identical to **include** except upon failure it will also
> produce a fatal **E_COMPILE_ERROR** level error. In other words, it will
> halt the script whereas include only emits a warning (**E_WARNING**) which
> allows the script to continue.

So this example shows the file at the root.

```
require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cons.php');
```

If it's below the `DocumentRoot` then you would do this:

```
require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../cons.php');
```

On another note, replace all of the `mysql_` functions with `mysqli_`. New versions of PHP will not include it as `mysql_` [has been deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying a SQL query without selecting a database first, mysql fails with the error "No database selected"

The error is displayed with the code `die(mysql_error());`. die aborts further execution of the script. If you'd like it to continue you should just `print` it instead like this

```
if($rs === FALSE) {
    print(mysql_error() . "\n"); // TODO: better error handling
}
else {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
        // Write the value of the column FirstName (which is now in the array $row)
        echo $row['url'] . "<br />";
    }
    // Close the database connection
    mysql_close();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you missing the semicolon (;) in the include?

Btw, you could set

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);
      ini_set('display_errors', '1'); ?>
```

this will show you the errors in your script.